# Deflection of Acrylic Shelf

Tags: structural-engineering, construction-management

I am installing an acrylic shelf, 75-1/4" L x 10" W x 1-1/2" deep.
It is fixed to the wall at the short ends. Should I be worried about deflection in the center of the shelf when weight is added? Is there anything I can do to calculate this?

Comment: You need the Youngs Modulus of the Acrylic you're using. Then it's simple maths. You can use this [website](http://www.aps.anl.gov/APS_Engineering_Support_Division/Mechanical_Operations_and_Maintenance/Calculators/ElasticBeam2.html) and it should tell you your deflection.

Comment: What load are you expecting? How is it distributed? What would be the maximum acceptable deflection?

Comment: @3kstc I think your comment, extended with some details, would look much better as an acceptable answer as a reason to close.